# How to check if selected regex word contains a substring?

Tags: regex

I have created a regex to match a `.vue` component.

It should match all components that have a basename that **does not** end with `Async`. So all `.vue` components should match except components with a filename(without the extension) ending in `Async`.

So these should not match

```
./deals/deal/countdown/CountdownWarningAsync.vue
./test/deal/countdown/SomeComponentAsync.vue
```

And these should.

```
./deals/deal/countdown/AsyncCountdownWarning.vue
./deals/deal/countdown/SomeComponent.vue    
./recenthotels/RecentHotels.vue
```

I know how to capture it without the `Async` part but how do I check for the basename **not** ending with `Async`?

https://regex101.com/r/0vXtGf/1

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't support lookbehinds or to be honest, it has an immature implementation on Google Chrome's V8 engine but other major browsers hasn't done it.

Use a negative lookahead:

```
\/[A-Z](?!\w*Async\.vue$)\w+\.vue$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0Ikfd/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `\/[A-Z]` Match `/` and a capital letter
- `(?!` Start of negative lookahead

  - `\w*` Match following letters
  - `Async\.vue$` up to this
- `)` End of lookahead
- `\w+` Match word characters
- `\.vue$` up to `.vue` extension

Answer (score 0):

If you want only matched `filename without extension`, you can try this,

```
[^\/]*(?<!Async)(?=\.vue)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/141)